SQL Server Agent Job Execution Based on a Trigger
I have following scenario to tackle some Production data gaps for various reports in a Datawarehouse:

We have few reporting tables, which get refreshed everyday with SQL server agent jobs. Jobs are scheduled at hard time.
There are a lot of other tables which are populated with the help of EOD batches triggered through another system.
SQL Agent related tables are dependent on the tables loaded in step 2.

In usual process, step 2 tables are always loaded first. However, in some rare scenarios, step 2 tables get delayed due to certain reasons. And due to that, step 1 tables get impacted as latest data haven't arrived by that time.
In order to resolve these data gaps issue for certain days, I am thinking to make the SQL agent jobs dependent on EOD batch jobs. i.e. Based on certain data in some tables, can we make a trigger for SQL agent jobs? I looked the configurations of those agent jobs, however, could not see anything related to trigger-based execution. Any leads will help to overcome the issue.
Have scheduled the jobs in SQL Server Agent but could not make those dependent on some trigger.

Track the status of your ETL loads in a database table. Run your SQL server agent every 5 mins and check if all the ETLs are complete for the day, and if so do your report calculations and flag the reports complete for the day so that every future run of the agent knows there is nothing to do.

SQL Server Agent jobs also run once a day. And those jobs are TRUNCATE and INSERT. If I run agent jobs every 5 minutes, it will TRUNCATE data every 5 minutes, that will not be feasible, as data gets consumed during the day. Agent jobs we run before the work starts.

As I said you run the agent every 5 mins, but you check the database status tables to see if you actually do anything. So you have a workflow system, as each stage is complete you carry out the next operation.

Starting an agent job in a trigger is a poor idea; you'd need to give the LOGINs that your users are using (to alter data) permissions to start agent jobs, which is far too permissive. @DaleK is right; log the completion of the task and have a more regular agent job check if there's any additional work to be done.

Thom, End users are not doing anything with agent jobs, this is Admin level process that we have some ETLs (Data Loads) via agent jobs and some via another ETL tool. So having the option to trigger the agent jobs based on some trigger should not give data alter permissions to end users.

Regarding idea of Dale, how agent will come to know that there is something to do and there is nothing to do. Let's say I have the ETL stats stored in a table, and I can tell at any point of time if ETLs are completed or no. Any leads to that, please. Thanks

In your agent you call a stored procedure which carries out any logic the needs to be carried out. As part of that you query your status table to see if all the data is ready to be processed.
